# How do i get notification in android when realtime data will change by FCM?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I m trying to set push notification in android device when firebase realtime database change.
***Suppose,if installed app was killed or run in background, if Any user post message in a group(new child added in Post node) and if Group has child named currentUid than i will get notification.***

This is post node in which user can post message.

```
"Post": 
    "pushId":{
              "message": "this is a group post"
             },
    "pushId2":{
              "message": "this is a group post2"
             },
```

This is group node of user.

```
"Group": {
            "gkgekugkiwughkiguvwvhvuh": true,
            "***currentUSERID***": true,
            "wkuuwkbuerkigubgi3ugnbgk": true
        },
```

So how i used FCM to complete this feature

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as too broad to reasonably answer in a single post on Stack Overflow. This is a complex piece of JavaScript that uses multiple technologies to implement  specific use-case. If you don't know JavaScript, your first step would be to learn that in a context that doesn't involve other complex technologies. Then do the same for each other individual technology. Once you've done that, combines your learnings, and the code you found should start to make more sense. At that point you can ask a more targeted question.

Comment: Okay i edited my question

Comment: `below javascript code` there is no code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by writing cloud function.

1) Add device_token to you user node.

[image: Demo]

2) Write a cloud function which will be called once a data get created and will send a notification to receiver.

```
    export const onMessageAdded = functions.database.
         ref('/chat/{whichNodes}/{chatId}').onCreate((snapShot, context) => {

 var message = {
                apns: {
                    payload: {
                        aps: {
                            alert: {
                                title: "Easee",
                                body: nameToNotify + " has sent you message",
                            },
                            sound: '1',
                            badge: 1,
                        },
                        notification: {
                            senderId: messageDataForUserOne.senderId + '',
                            receiverId: messageDataForUserOne.receiverId + '',
                            notificationMessage: messageDataForUserOne.message + '',
                            name: nameToNotify,
                            notificationType: "Push"
                        }
                    }
                },
                android: {

                    data: {
                        senderId: messageDataForUserOne.senderId + '',
                        receiverId: messageDataForUserOne.receiverId + '',
                        notificationMessage: messageDataForUserOne.message + '',
                        name: nameToNotify,
                        notificationType: "Push"
                    }
                },
                token: userDeviceToken
            };

            admin.messaging().send(message).then(suc => {
                console.log('Notification send Successfuly.' + suc)
            }).catch(errorr => {
                console.log('Notification Failed.' + userDeviceToken
                )
            })
        }
```